# How do I do a people search on Myspace.com in c#?

Tags: api, search, myspace

I have been to so many sites and documentation pages trying to access the myspace search function via an API call. This function is located at http://searchservice.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=sitesearch.friendfinder.

With MySpace's extensive APIs for everything, I can't seem to find a way to access a simple search in code! Whats more is, I don't even need (or want) OAUTH authentication, I just want a simple public search, without having to hack apart the HTML page result from the URL above.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

MySpace has recently launched a search API based on the OpenSearch standard.

See here for more info.: http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Open_Search